# Fixing the Playstation tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

So, we have [playstation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/playstation), which is self-explanatory

But we have some confusingly ambiguous tags

- [ps2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps2) - Refers mostly to the PS/2 port, which is an older connector for keyboards and mice
- [ps3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps3) - Refers to the Playstation 3. Strangely, [playstation3] is a synonym. Unfortunately, [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) has PS3 as an input prompt
- [ps4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps4) - Refers to the Playstation 4

I don't think there's anything to be done to [ps2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps2). It's being used properly for the most part.

[ps3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps3) should have its synonym reversed and become [playstation3]

[ps4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ps4) should be renamed [playstation4], with [ps4] as a synonym

This both disambiguates the tags and keeps the nomenclature the same.

Comment: A bit sad you didn't include [tag:ps1] and then looking in [ps] you come across this [g e m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50701840/spring-data-use-mixed-annotatnions-on-domain-classes-spring-data-mongo-and-spri)

Comment: @rene Can't mess with [the classics](https://blog.us.playstation.com/2018/09/18/introducing-playstation-classic-with-20-pre-loaded-games/)

Comment: They sold half a billion of them, acronym-wise it has "ibm" and "php" chops.  "Playstation" today refers to the network that gamers subscribe to and use to find each other to play together, not exactly the kind of users you'd want to ask for help here.

Comment: @HansPassant Normally I'd suggest a burninate, but the [ps3] and [ps4] tags seem on-topic so it doesn't pass the test for that. I'm just suggesting we make the tags less ambiguous

Comment: "but the [ps3] and [ps4] tags seem on-topic" example of on topic questions that wouldn't be properly tagged without these tags?

Comment: @Braiam [This question about PS4 controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52527832/sdl2-qt-c-not-reading-joystick-inputs-but-recognized). [Another PS4 controller coding question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194587/arduino-dualshock-4-c)

Comment: @Machavity nope, both are about joysticks, not the console. If I buy a PS4 I expect getting a console, not just the controls.

Comment: @HansPassant thats kinda messed up, I play on PSN all the time, and still ask questions here all the time. Why wouldn't SO want me here?

Comment: Maybe best to disjoint `playstation3` from `ps3` and `ps4` from `playstation4`: i.e. **no synonym at all**. That way all tags can have distinct usages. That's quite doable with this low number of questions.

Comment: @Braiam But no one wants another tag for ps controllers so ps4 is a perfectly fine tag....

Comment: @EpicKip we don't need another tag, we already have [tag:joystick] for all of them. End result: less tags.

Comment: @Braiam: PS4 controllers are not joysticks.

Comment: @user2357112 what is the controller made of? Buttons and analog sticks each with hardware interrupts, isn't it? That's called on every piece of software that deals with HID hardware joysticks. The two questions Machavity linked above call them joysticks.

Comment: @Braiam: Those questions are using APIs designed for joysticks that were somewhat awkwardly reused for other controller types, and the second question is using "joystick" to refer to the analog sticks. Not everything that uses joystick APIs is a joystick, just like not everything transferred through the HyperText Transfer Protocol is hypertext.

Comment: @user2357112 is there anything fundamentally different between a joystick and any controller? All controllers are joystick and can be abstracted into the same elements joysticks have: buttons and sticks. Why are you so adamant to recognize that there isn't anything special about any controller.

Comment: @Braiam: Maybe there's a regional difference here, like how "pants" means "underpants" or "trousers" to different people, but to me, "joystick" means something like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joystick#/media/File:Joyopis.svg). It doesn't matter whether there's "anything special" about different controller types; "joystick" means one type of controller specifically.